# Split vector into groups based on the sum of the elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, grouping

I am writing a program that needs to group objects based on the sum of their weight. Every object has a weight(int); I need to make groups of objects where the sum of the weights for each group is in a range, for example between 800-900.

This is my most recent attempt:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> segmentate(std::map<int, int>* nodeMap)
{
    int sumWeight = 0;
    int nodeWeight = 0;
    std::vector<int> copyVector;
    std::vector<int> groupVector;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> groups;

    for (auto& c_it = nodeMap->begin(); c_it != nodeMap->end(); ++c_it)
    {
        copyVector.push_back(c_it->second);
    }

    for (auto& n_it = copyVector.begin(); n_it != copyVector.end(); ++n_it)
    {
        nodeWeight = *n_it;
        if (nodeWeight > 800)
        {
            groupVector.push_back(*n_it);
            groups.push_back(groupVector);
            groupVector.clear();
        }
        else
        {
            sumWeight += nodeWeight;
            if (sumWeight < 800)
            {
                groupVector.push_back(*n_it);
            }
            else
            {
                if (sumWeight > 900)
                {
                    if (nodeWeight > 200)
                    {
                         sumWeight -= nodeWeight;
                         copyVector.push_back(*n_it);
                         copyVector.erase(n_it);
                         --n_it;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        groupVector.push_back(*n_it);
                        groups.push_back(groupVector);
                        groupVector.clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return groups;
}
```

Obviously, in most of the cases this code will enter an infinite loop, but it's only an approach to try to explain the problem. Is there any known algorithm to accomplish this task? If not, can someone help me to channel the solution?

Comment: This sounds like a [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: Are you trying to group a number of elements until the sum of their weight is between 800 and 900?

Comment: What is the objective of this optimization?

Comment: Yes Mike P.  I will take a look to the knapsack problem. Thanks to both of you.